# Laravel routes return 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I deploy basic Laravel project to server. When I hit my domain it returns default welcome view. When I add simple road (see below) to code and try to enter that route in browser it returns 500 internal error. All routes return 500 error except the "/" root route.

Folder structure:

```
/
#laravel
#subdoms
##api
```

Laravel files are in laravel directory except files from public directory which are in api diretory.

.htaccess file in api directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Storage directory and everything in it is writeable, readable, executable for anyone.

There are no error logs in laravel/storage/logs.

laravel/routes/web.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () { // works fine.
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('hello', function () { // 500 internal error
    return 'Hello world';
});
```

Server info:

Server
- Linux CentOS 
- Apache 2.2 
- Server Side Includes - SSI 
- PHP Version 7.0.17

Comment: hello or /hello?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: yes it is.  "/" means route file. where you have called welcome.blade.php so further calls which you want to do will come after that "/".

Comment: Where do you see that in the documentation @AshishPatel?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing uses plenty of examples, one being `users/` (not in the `Route::group()` section) that does not use `/users/`

Answer (score 8):

For those who just reading this through, and still have no solution, it could be that you just cloned a project from a repo on your gitlab or github account and forgot to generate the .env file and APP_KEY init. so go to your project directory and open a terminal and run `cp .env.example .env`. this would create the `.env` file. then run `php artisan key:generate`.

**just note that in my special case laravel returned 500 error for every route.**

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:**

add '/' before all your routes; your case '/hello'.  Or ;

**Solution2:**

I guess .htaccess is ignored. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride

```
*apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 : *

ServerName localhost

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

**Solution 3:**

Apache may be configured to deny .htaccess overrides. In that case you'll need to add a segment in your VirtualHost configuration allowing those. See the Apache documentation for more information. It also may be the case that mod_rewrite is not enabled. If using Ubuntu, Debian or other Debian-based OS is used a sudo a2enmod rewrite followed by sudo service apache2 reload will suffice.

Here is mine and it works

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel51/public/
   # change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It works fine on localhost. When I put it on server I have to remove: <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule> because with this I can not load even the index file.

Comment: check to see if u have ur .htaccess on ur public folder.   Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on your server.  Also, .htaccess may be disabled on your server for security reasons. Try putting your mod_rewrite on your <VirtualHost> or <Directory> section.   There might be AllowOverride on several places if you are using Virtual Host for your websites. So make sure to aff AllowOverride All on all configs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're having this error with Laravel 8+, just add the following

```
RewriteBase /
```

Before line 6 in the .htaccess file in public. It worked for me